# trying to download documents in zip file get this error ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Tags: php, laravel, php-ziparchive

i am trying to download documents and pictures means files in zip using PHP in laravel application but it throughs the following error i checked everywhere online but not found any solution

```
ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object
```

method

```
public function downoad()
   $officeSpecs = DB::table('specifications_draged_files')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        $files = array();

        foreach ($officeSpecs as $officeSpec) {
            $files[] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/public/uploads/zsdf_specs/' . Auth::user()->id . '/files/' . $officeSpec->draged_file;
        }
        $zipname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'public/uploads/zsdf_specs/office_specs.zip';
        $zip = new \ZipArchive();

        $zip->open($zipname, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
        if ($zip->open($zipname) != true) {
            dd("Could not open archive");
        }
        $i= 0;
        foreach ($files as $key => $file) {

            if (file_exists($file)) {

                $zip->addFile($file);
            }

        }

        $zip->close();

        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
        readfile($zipname);
}
```

Comment: did u define ' use ZipArchive; ' at top  ?

Comment: yes i did that why other funcntions of ZipArchive are working except this one $zip->addFile($file); @fahim152

Comment: please edit and show us the full method

Comment: @fahim152 done this was the complete funciton